# In PyCharm how to create multiple .py(Python) files with enumeration in Project Folder with one click?

Tags: python, pycharm

[image]

Now, I'm solving programming problems from one book. I'm trying to post all answers to the problems from that book on github after solving all of them in Python. I always give enumeration to names of problems, for example: 1.py, 2.py etc...
But that's very time consuming is there anyway that I can create multiple python files with one click giving start and range and name them by iteration index, for example:
For i in range(1, 41):
create i.py file "in some location"
??????

Is there a easy way to these enumeration of multiple files????

Comment: What exactly is the issue you are encountering?

Comment: I just posted image for explanation

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want but I may be wrong

```
for i in range(0, 5):
    f = open(str(i) + '.py', 'x')
    f.close()
```

Comment: Cleaner: `with open(f'{i}.py', 'x'): pass`